# que signifie l'expression "voler le temps"?

Tags: grammaire, sens, traduction

Salut,
"Aimer c'est **voler le temps**."
voler **le** temps - c'est comme "s'emparer de" ou "planer"?
Pourriez-vous m'aider ? Merci d'avance !

Comment: Comme _s'emparer de_, _prendre_. De toute façon, _planer_ n'est pas un verbe transifit. On ne _plane_ pas _qqchose_.

Comment: Aucun contexte n'est donné mais il semble qu'il s'agisse d'un extrait d'[*Aimer*](https://www.paroles.cc/chanson,aimer,14734) (Roméo & Juliette).  Je prends ces mots au sens propres mais on peut comprendre ce qu'on veut, c'est une question d'interprétation. Le parolier a des contraintes de rythme et de rime. Le sens des paroles est à mon avis secondaire, la chanson a été traduite dans beaucoup de langues et si on compare les versions, les paroles diffèrent beaucoup d'une langue à l'autre. [Article wikipedia](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aimer_(chanson)) sur la chanson.

Comment: @Frank je vois que les t et les f, ce sont des caractères transitifs :)

Comment: Oui, Roméo & Juliette.

Comment: Je pense que c'est comme "le temps vole". Mais "voler le temps" c'est le verbe intransitif.

Comment: *Voler le temps* et *le temps vole* ne veulent pas dire la même chose. « Voler le temps » est une construction transitive, *voler* est  donc ici synonyme de *dérober* (steal/klauen/robar/rubare).  Dans « un oiseau vole » la construction est intransitive, *voler* veut dire *voltiger* (a bird flies/un ave vuela/ ein Vogel fliegt).

Comment: Mais on ne dirait pas _voler le temps_ pour _faire voler le temps_.

Comment: Merci à tous pour vos réponses !

Answer (score 2):

Le verbe *voler* a deux sens différents.

Quand il est **intransitif** ([Verbe 1](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/voler#Fran%C3%A7ais) dans le wiktionnaire) il veut dire, « bouger/ **se maintenir dans les airs** » :

> un oiseau vole.

Quand il est **transitif** ([Verbe 2](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/voler#Fran%C3%A7ais) dans le wiktionnaire) il veut dire **dérober**.

> Quelqu'un est en train de voler ma voiture.

« Voler le temps »  veut dire « dérober le temps ».

« Voler le temps » a un sens très différent de « le temps vole ». De toutes façons en français « le temps vole » n'est pas une expression toute faite qui serait l'équivalent de l'anglais *time flies*, en français *times flies* se dit « le temps passe très vite » (« le temps file vite » si on veut quelque chose de plus imagé).

Comment: Merci beaucoup.